# Can Texinfo's @value macro be made to work in the filename argument to @xref and friends?

Tags: pdftex, expansion, texinfo

Given a file `xref-and-value.texi` with contents:

```
\input texinfo @c -*- TeX-PDF-mode: t; -*-
@setfilename xref-and-value.info
@settitle @code{@@xref} and @code{@@value} in \pdftex

@set fngccint gccint-4.6
@xref{Top,,Introduction, @value{fngccint}, GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) Internals}.
@bye
```

I get this output from **pdfTeX**:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian) (format=pdftex 2012.2.28)  5 MAR 2012 17:13
entering extended mode
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**\input xref-and-value.texi
(./xref-and-value.texi (/usr/share/texmf/tex/texinfo/texinfo.tex
Loading texinfo [version 2008-04-18.10]:
```

...

```
 formatting,
\defaultparindent=\dimen46
 and turning on texinfo input format.)
(./xref-and-value.aux)
\openout1 = `xref-and-value.aux'.

@cpindfile=@write2
@fnindfile=@write3
@vrindfile=@write4
@tpindfile=@write5
@kyindfile=@write6
@pgindfile=@write7

! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
@makevalueexpandable ->@let @value
                                   = @expandablevalue @catcode `@-=@other @c...

@value ->@begingroup @makevalueexpandable
                                          @valuexxx
@makevalueexpandable ->@let @value
                                   = @expandablevalue @catcode `@-=@other @c...

@value ->@begingroup @makevalueexpandable
                                          @valuexxx
@makevalueexpandable ->@let @value
                                   = @expandablevalue @catcode `@-=@other @c...

@value ->@begingroup @makevalueexpandable
                                          @valuexxx
...
l.6 ...}, GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) Internals}
                                                  .
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

([This is a known limitation of `texinfo.tex`.](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-texinfo/2008-03/msg00033.html))

So, it looks like the 4th argument to `@xref` is being used in an expand-only context, but that `@value` isn't (usefully) expandable.

Can the `@set`/`@value` facility be re-implemented such that `@value` *is* expandable?

---

**Update**:

In response to Bruno's comment about `@expandablevalue`, I tried this:

```
\errorcontextlines 100 \input texinfo @c -*- TeX-PDF-mode: t; -*-

@setfilename xref-and-value.info
@settitle @code{@@xref} and @code{@@value} in \pdftex

@set fngccint gccint-4.6
@xref{Top,,Introduction, @expandablevalue{fngccint}, GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) Internals}.
@bye
```

This at least manages to typeset, but still generates errors:

```
! Argument of @expandablevalue has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                @par
<to be read again>
                   }
@addtokens ...f @addtoks {@noexpand #1={@the #1#2}
                                                  }@addtoks
@skipspaces ...@else @addtokens {@filename }{@PP }
                                                  @advance @filenamelength b...
<argument>  @expandablevalue
                             {fngccint}
@getfilename ...ngth =0@expandafter @skipspaces #1
                                                  |@relax
@xrefX ...nofonts @turnoffactive @getfilename {#4}
                                                  {@activebackslashdouble @x...
l.7 ...}, GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) Internals}
                                                  .
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before @expandablevalue was complete.
<to be read again>
                   @par
<to be read again>
                   }
@addtokens ...f @addtoks {@noexpand #1={@the #1#2}
                                                  }@addtoks
@skipspaces ...@else @addtokens {@filename }{@PP }
                                                  @advance @filenamelength b...
<argument>  @expandablevalue
                             {fngccint}
@getfilename ...ngth =0@expandafter @skipspaces #1
                                                  |@relax
@xrefX ...nofonts @turnoffactive @getfilename {#4}
                                                  {@activebackslashdouble @x...
l.7 ...}, GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) Internals}
                                                  .
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

Comment: It seems `@expandablevalue` is meant as an expandable version of `@value`.  But I'm too lazy to dig carefully.  (And somewhat disturbed by the choice of `@` as an escape character.)

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: Hmm, doesn't *quite* seem to work. (And at least `texinfo.tex` isn't full of `@`!)

Comment: Yay, a Texinfo question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fourth argument of `@xref` is parsed as a filename by `@getfilename` (to see that, look for `#4` in the log output of `@show@xref`).  This function reads its argument one macro parameter at a time, and expands those independently.  When receiving `@expandablevalue{fngccint}`, it will first read `@expandablevalue` and try to expand it (within an `@edef`), but fail because `{fngccint}` is not within that `@edef`.

A solution is to put braces around `@expandablevalue{fngccint}`: then it is grabbed as one macro parameter, and the expansion works.

```
\errorcontextlines 100 \input texinfo @c -*- TeX-PDF-mode: t; -*-

@setfilename xref-and-value.info
@settitle @code{@@xref} and @code{@@value} in \pdftex

@set fngccint gccint-4.6
@xref{Top,,Introduction, {@expandablevalue{fngccint}}, GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) Internals}.
@bye
```

Comment: Oh, good catch! I *had* realized that `\getfilename`/`\skipspaces` effectively looped over the input token list item-by-item, but somehow missed the fact that this was reckoned *before* macro-expansion. I wonder if I can figure out how to change it to expand macros as it goes...

Comment: The immensely useful `\expandafter\foo\romannumeral-\`q` construction is your friend then (nothing special about the character `q` here).  Due to subtleties of TeX's grammar, `-\`q` is an incomplete (negative) number: it can be followed by an optional space.  Hence, TeX continues looking ahead, expanding tokens as it goes, until finding a space or a nonexpandable token.  The big drawback of this command is that is loses spaces.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, if anyone runs into this problem in the future, [it's been fixed in `texinfo.tex`](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/texinfo/texinfo/doc/texinfo.tex?view=log#rev1.362), so you can just grab the latest `texinfo.tex` and use that.  (This is actually what upstream suggests that *everyone* do; just search for `texinfo.tex` on [the Texinfo webpage](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/))